# Relation between simple critical points of Hamiltonian and gradient systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm doing some exercices to see how are related the hamiltonian and the gradient systems. I did an exercise, but I don't know if my approach is correct and I have a few questions about it. Let's state it:

> Let $H:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^2$ function. We consider the Hamiltonian:
>
> \begin{cases}\dot{x}=-\frac{\partial H(x,y)}{\partial y}\\ \dot{y}=\frac{\partial H(x,y)}{\partial x}\end{cases}
>
> and the gradient systems:
>
> \begin{cases}\dot{x}=\frac{\partial H(x,y)}{\partial x}\\ \dot{y}=\frac{\partial H(x,y)}{\partial y}\end{cases}
>
> a) Given an ODE on the plane, we'd say that a **simple** critical point is a critical point whose eigenvalues are different of $0$. Prove that if we have a simple critical point for one of those systems, it's also a simple critical point for the other one.

So here's my try:

> Let's suppose that we have a simple critical point for a hamiltonian system. We know that if $(x,y)$ is a simple critical point, we have
>
> \begin{cases}\dot{x}=-\frac{\partial H(x,y)}{\partial y}=0\\ \dot{y}=\frac{\partial H(x,y)}{\partial x}=0\end{cases}
>
> It's straightforward that:
>
> \begin{cases}\frac{\partial H(x,y)}{\partial x}=0\\ \frac{\partial H(x,y)}{\partial y}=0\end{cases}
>
> so it's a simple critical point of the gradient system too.

It's correct?

The condition of "simple" means that $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$?

Thanks.

Comment: You are just using the definition of critical point, i.e. $(\dot{x},\dot{y})=(0,0)$ to say that if $(x,y)$ is a critical point of one of the two systems then it is a critical point of the other. Maybe it helps to understand to which eigenvalues you are refering to

Comment: I think that it's referring to the eigenvalues of the matrix evaluated on this simple critical point

Comment: Note that there is no matrix yet.

Comment: @JohnMa  So how I have to solve this problem then? Because I copied the statement exactly as it’s on the notes

Comment: You really need to answer this question (posted by Uskebasi): to show that a critical point is simple, you have to check the eigenvalue, but eigenvalue of which matrix?

Comment: @JohnMa I really don’t know how to answer this question because I’ve only defined what a hamiltonian system is on my notes, nothing else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a system 
\begin{cases}
\dot x = F^1(x, y),\\ 
\dot y=F^2(x, y)
\end{cases}
and a critical point $(x_0, y_0)$, we consider the Jacobian matrix

$$ DF(x_0, y_0) = \begin{pmatrix}
F^1_x(x_0,y_0) & F^2_x(x_0,y_0) \\  F^1_y(x_0,y_0) & F^2_y(x_0,y_0)
\end{pmatrix}$$

the critical point is called simple, if the eigenvalue of this matrix are both nonzero. Note that this is the same as saying that $DF$ has nonzero determinant.

Now you are given both the Hamiltonian system $(Ha)$ and the gradient system $(G)$ of a function $H$. You checked already that $(x_0, y_0)$ is critical point of $(Ha)$ iff it is a critical point of $(G)$.

Now try to calculate the Jacobian matrix of both system. For the gradient system, you would get the Hessian matrix of $H$. For the Hamiltonian system, you got a very similar matrix. You can check that they have the same determinant.

Comment: @Relure, now you have all the ingredients!